# How to change the return value in Excel to the content of a specific cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!L:L;B6 & "," & C6) > 0; "x"; "")
```

Columns `B` and `C` contains last and first name of employees (`B6` = Cook, `C6` = Jim).
In row `L` of *Sheet2* is the same content, but its in one single row divided by a comma (eq. Cook, Jim).
The formula compares the 2 sheets until it finds a match. Now I want the formula the return the value of a cell in the same line where the match was found. The cell contains the employees ID and is located in row `K`.

For example if the name from `B6:C6` is found in *Sheet2* in row `L28`, then the formula should return the employees ID from `K28` and if `B6:C6` is found in row `L200` then the return value is `K200`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of your data to reference?

Comment: You can make dummy-data (made-up data) from what you're working with and your expected outcome from the code.

Comment: Why can't you make a simplified example with dummy data? You expect for help with your issue but somehow do not want to collaborate

Comment: Sorry I added it. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `VLOOKUP`: [vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) with concatenated string should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&","&B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"Nor found")
```

Result:

[image]

Could use `TRIM`: [trim](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) or combination of `TRIM` and `CLEAN`: [clean](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) in addition to avoid errors caused by leading, trailing spaces and unprintable characters:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(VLOOKUP(CLEAN(TRIM(A2))&","&CLEAN(TRIM(B2)),CLEAN(TRIM(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4)),2,FALSE)),"Not found")
```

Note that exact range of data in *Sheet2* ($A$1:$B$4 instead of A:B) is used in this case to not slow Excel down.

Comment: Could add trim() for A2 and B2, as extra spaces can cause many false errors. plus 1